# cp doesn't work in script but works in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Now, this is a strange problem, I have this kind of script:

```
CWD="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)"
RESOURCES_PATH="${CWD}/resources"

PROJECT_NAME="something"

DRUSH_ALIASES_EXAMPLE_PATH="${RESOURCES_PATH}/example.aliases.drushrc.php"
DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH="~/.drush/${PROJECT_NAME}.aliases.drushrc.php"

cp ${DRUSH_ALIASES_EXAMPLE_PATH} ${DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH}
echo "cp ${DRUSH_ALIASES_EXAMPLE_PATH} ${DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH}"
```

When I'm trying to run that kind of script, I'm getting error: "cp: Cannot create regular file "~/.drush/something.aliases.drushrc.php". There is no such file or directory"

But the funny thing is, that if I will copy the output of "echo" and paste in directly into terminal, the command will work just fine. I'm confused, any ideas what can be wrong with above script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `$HOME/.drush...` instead of `~/.drush....` the `"~"` does not seem to be expanded to your home directory.

Comment: Yep, because `~` is not expanded when quoted. Of course, the arguments to `cp` really ought to be quoted as well, to avoid surprises.

Comment: `~/"quoted name"` will work, as well.

Answer (score 2):

The tilde `~` character to mean the home directory only works at the beginning of a word, at the beginning of a value being assigned, or (for the purposes of PATH assignments) after a colon in a value being assigned. It must not be quoted.

Since `~` is expanded by the shell, the fact that you see it reported by `cp` means that you have a shell expansion problem.

Here the tilde is within double quotes, so it isn't expanded. Use either of these:

```
DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH=~/".drush/${PROJECT_NAME}.aliases.drushrc.php"
DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH="$HOME/.drush/${PROJECT_NAME}.aliases.drushrc.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` you can also use internal string subsitution via [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to replace the tilde character `~` with the value of `$HOME`.

Not very elegant, but could be useful if you are uncertain about a possible `~` character in a file path string passed on to you (not the case here).

```
unset HOME
HOME="$(eval 'echo ~')"

- cp ${DRUSH_ALIASES_EXAMPLE_PATH} ${DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH}
+ cp "${DRUSH_ALIASES_EXAMPLE_PATH/#\~/${HOME}}" "${DRUSH_ALIASES_PATH/#\~/${HOME}}"
```