# Linux "cp" command inside bash script

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

OriginFilePath="/home/lv2eof/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/"
OriginFileName="Bookmarks"
OriginFilePathAndName="$OriginFilePath""$OriginFileName"

DestinationFilePath="/home/Config/Browser/Bookmarks/ScriptSaved/Chrome/Profile 1/"
DestinationFileName=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-Bookmarks)
DestinationFilePathAndName="$DestinationFilePath""$DestinationFileName"

echo cp \"$OriginFilePathAndName\" \"$DestinationFilePathAndName\"
cp \"$OriginFilePathAndName\" \"$DestinationFilePathAndName\"
```

When I execute it from the command line I get this output:

```
[~/]
lv2eof@PERU $$$ csbp1
cp "/home/lv2eof/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/Bookmarks" "/home/Config/Browser/Bookmarks/ScriptSaved/Chrome/Profile 1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks"
cp: target '1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks"' is not a directory

[~/]
lv2eof@PERU $$$
```

So I get an error and the file isn't copied.
Nevertheless if I issue in the command line the command:

```
[~/]
lv2eof@PERU $$$ cp "/home/lv2eof/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/Bookmarks" "/home/Config/Browser/Bookmarks/ScriptSaved/Chrome/Profile 1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks"

[~/]
lv2eof@PERU $$$
```

As you can see everything works fine and the file is copied.
Shouldn't the commands work the same inside and outside bash scripts?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cp doesn't work in script but works in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103359/cp-doesnt-work-in-script-but-works-in-terminal)

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes in the script? That causes them to be interpreted literally instead of being used to account for the spaces. When accounting for the that, what is happening is rather evident.

Comment: It's because you escaped the double quote on the cp command. The destination path variable splits into two paths.

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658837/preserving-double-quotes-in-a-command-created-from-variables-in-shell-script/658839#658839 - using `echo` instead of `-x`.

Comment: Note that the command that you typed in the terminal isn't the same as the one you typed in the script. Try `cp \"/home/lv2eof/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1/Bookmarks\" \"/home/Config/Browser/Bookmarks/ScriptSaved/Chrome/Profile 1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks\"` in the terminal and you'll get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps hard to notice, but message gives you two hints:

```
cp: target '1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks"' is not a directory
           |                           |
           |                           +-- Notice quote
           +-- Space in target
```

In other words `1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks"` is not a directory. So why is it saying that?

In your script you have:

```
cp \"$OriginFilePathAndName\" \"$DestinationFilePathAndName\"
```

By ***escaping the quotes***, you are saying the quotes are part of the arguments. Or: threat quotes as literal text. They are *concatenated* with the value of the variable.

Should be:

```
cp "$OriginFilePathAndName" "$DestinationFilePathAndName"
```

In short: you quote the variable to tell bash *this should be threaded as one argument*.

From your question, the actual arguments to `cp` becomes 4, not 2:

1. `"/home/lv2eof/.config/google-chrome/Profile`
2. `1/Bookmarks"`
3. `"/home/Config/Browser/Bookmarks/ScriptSaved/Chrome/Profile`
4. `1/20211207-001444-Bookmarks"`

In other words copy 1, 2 and 3 into 4.

Comment: You are right. I tried your sugestion and it worked fine. The explenation for my mistake is simple: still newbie after all these years :)